# Is it possible to build a GUI using platform-native code (i.e. Cocoa) in QT?

Tags: cocoa, qt, user-interface, cross-platform

Is it possible to build a GUI using platform-native code, like Cocoa, in QT?

Do you know of any resources or links that show examples or demonstrations of how to get started doing this?

I can only find sites that explain how QT uses interfaces to link to the Cocoa API, which seems to imply that the UI is still built with QT and it doesn't support platform-specific technology like Core Animation, etc.

Thanks
Turgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, you can combine Objective C code using cocoa with C++/Qt code. There are not too many people doing it though, so it will be a bit of an experiment.

Have a look at these [Qt wrappers for Cocoa widgets](https://github.com/mikemcquaid/Qocoa#readme) to see how it can work.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried to do it but I think it should be possible. I suggest you try to read this: http://el-tramo.be/blog/mixing-cocoa-and-qt/.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can set your QStyle, such as QMacStyle. Check out more here:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/style-reference.html

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP is aware of how to build a Qt Mac-style UI, but he wants to know if it's possible to make the UI using native Cocoa with the back-end code in Qt.

Comment: Yes Rob that's right. I want to know if it's possible to make the UI using native Cocoa with the back-end code in Qt.